# How do I create a Binding of HTML node conditionally?

Tags: html, scala, dom, data-binding, binding.scala

I want to conditionally create a Binding of HTML node.

```
@dom def maybeEmpty: Binding[Node] = {
  if (math.random > 0.5) {
    <div>non-empty content</div>
  }
}
```

However the code does not compile.

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.scalajs.dom.raw.Node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `else` block with an empty content, usually a HTML comment:

```
@dom def maybeEmpty: Binding[Node] = {
  if (math.random > 0.5) {
    <div>non-empty content</div>
  } else {
    <!-- empty content -->
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Binding.scala 11.1.x you can write:

```
@dom def maybeEmpty: Binding[Option[Node]] = {
  if (math.random > 0.5) {
    Some(<div>non-empty content</div>)
  } else {
    None
  }
}
```